# Can't connect to mongoDB in docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm currently working on an api.
When I run my api on my local computer I can connect to MongoDB but when I run it from the docker container, I cannot connect to MongoDB

I tried this to connect to the container :
`mongodb://0.0.0.0:27018`
and
`mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018`

I also check if the two containers can communicate together and they can so I don't know how to do it

There is my docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  mongo:
    container_name: "sell-mongodb"
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db/
volumes:
  mongodb-data:
```

Comment: Use `docker inspect` to see what the ip of your mongodb container is

Comment: I didn't mention but I also tried using the IP it wasn't working

Comment: You could also set `network_mode: host` under your docker-compose mongo:

Comment: need to use same network in spec of those containers. see networking in docker for more help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `mongodb://mongo:27017`.

Use `mongo` as hostname, because it is the name of your MongoDB service in Docker Compose. By default, Docker enables you to access other containers by this service hostnames.

Do not use `27018` port when connecting from within another container, as it is a port exposed to your host machine. Port `27017` on the other hand should be accessible by default from the internal docker network, i.e. from other containers.
See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports